# Is there a bluetooth camera that works with an iMac?

Tags: camera, webcam, video-capture

I want to put a webcam in a far corner of my office and use it for Skype.

Do you know of a bluetooth or other wireless camera that will show up on a Mac like a regular camera?

Answer (score 1):

What exactly are looking for? A Security Camera? Take a look at BestBuy's, Amazon or the AppleStores camera section. Most USB, Bluetooth or Ethernet cameras should be supported out-of-the-box.

Here are some ideas:

[Withings Home HD WLAN  Video Camera](http://www.apple.com/shop/product/HH0T2ZM/A/withings-home-hd-video-camera?fnode=6618ffa8f5a01207f813b22034f830bcc2752ba14bb4a5beb765bbb971aa51855bd9e9cdc5ce87cc887bc9a9472c6a17c9487d1e7e90b65eccd1060159bd48ad83bf8706015b98f4a21f2553427a1b339c4cc7640ad1fdcf5f99d540c115dd4d)

[image: Withings Home HD WLAN Video Camera]

[Arlo Netgear Wire-Free](https://www.arlo.com/en-us/)

[image: Netgear Arlo Wire-Free]

[NetCam Wi-Fi Camera with Night Vision](http://www.belkin.com/us/F7D7601-Belkin/p/P-F7D7601/)
[image: NetCam Wi-Fi Camera with Night Vision]

Comment: Thanks. Do you know if OSX actually shows these cameras as webcams that can be accessed by other apps?

Comment: I don't see why this shouldn't be possible. e.g. in Skype you can select the video source.